# Launch PS1 as a user and call another PS1 as a current windows login user without password prompt

Tags: powershell

I have created a Powershell script that runs with my account for others to use. In the script, it has a button that launches Windows Remote Assist. The problem is, as the script runs with my account, my name appears in the receiver end. I can include `-credential` but it will prompt for a login detail. Is there a way to launch it as a current user without any prompt?

I have tried to call another .ps1 that processes msra /offerra but that still uses my credentials.

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C msra /offerra $StrComputer" -NoNewWindow
```

Is there a way to do it or is it even possible? I don't know end user's password so I cannot include it in my script.

Comment: Security wise, this sound like a very bad design and I suspect that the password is hardcoded in the first script. Instead of investigating a scripted solution for this, I would make sure users can just run their own rdp seasons.

Comment: Nope, using convertto-securestring, AES, and DPAPI, password is encrypted in a text file and my scripts just read from it. All uers can run their own RDP but my script does much more than that and for many functions, they just don't have enough access if using their own account. For now, I just use get-credential and they just have to type in their password to proceed.